# Disposing object from same object

Tags: c#, dispose, fluent

I'm designing a fluent API and the usage is somewhat like this:

```
IUser user = work
                 .Timeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
                 .WithRepository(c => c.Users)
                 .Do(r => r.LoadByUsername("matt"))
                 .Execute();
```

So, let's say that `work` is of type `IUnitOfWork`, but the method `WithRepository(c => c.Users)` returns an interface called `IActionFlow<IUserRepository>` which is `IDisposable`.

When I call `Execute()` and get the final result, I lose the reference to that `IActionFlow<IUserRepository>` instance so I can't dispose it.

What are the disadvantages of having the instance dipose itself on the `Execute()` method?

Something like:

```
public TResult Execute()
{
    // ...
    Dispose();
    return result;
}
```

The code seems to compile just fine but I'm looking for strange behaviors or bugs that may rise because of this. Is it bad practice at all?

Comment: Well it just means you return a disposed object wich does look weird :). Fluent interfaces have some issues: https://ocramius.github.io/blog/fluent-interfaces-are-evil/ there is a whole discussion Dispose pattern with fluent interfaces here: https://davefancher.com/2015/06/14/functional-c-fluent-interfaces-and-functional-method-chaining/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have `Using` method like this:

```
public static TResult Using<TDisposable, TResult>(Func<TDisposable> factory,
    Func<TDisposable, TResult> fn) where TDisposable : IDisposable {
    using (var disposable = factory()) {
        return fn(disposable);
    }
}
```

Then your code would look like this:

```
var user = Using(() => work.
    Timeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)).
    WithRepository(c => c.Users),
    repository => repository.Do(r => r.LoadByUsername("matt")).
        Execute());
```

This will allow your API to stay fluent and at the same time you will dispose `WithRepository` the same moment `Execute` is completed.

Comment: I like the cleverness of the solution but IMO it is overkill.

Answer (score 2):

Option 1:

Can you wrap your code inside the `using` block so that dispose will be called automatically,

```
using(var repository = work.Timeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)).WithRepository(c => c.Users))
{
   IUser user = repository
                 .Do(r => r.LoadByUsername("matt"))
                 .Execute();

}
```

Thus, your `Execute` method does not need to call `Dispose()`

```
public TResult Execute()
{
    // ...
    //Dispose();
    return result;
}
```

Option 2:

You can assign the result in a property and return the repository object using which you can call a `Dispose` method explicitly.

Something like this (can be refactored further),

```
using(var repository = work
                 .Timeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
                 .WithRepository(c => c.Users)
                 .Do(r => r.LoadByUsername("matt"))
                 .Execute())
{

   IUser user = repository.Result;
   //repository.Dispose();
}

//******

public TResult Result { get; set; }

public IActionFlow<IUserRepository> Execute()
{
    // ...
    //Dispose();
    this.Result = result;
    return this;
}
```

Note: After calling a `Dispose()` method, garbage collection may happen at any stage based on the available server resources. So calling this inside the `Execute` method might produce unexpected strange issues.

Comment: I can, but this will make my API not fluent at all

Comment: @MatiasCicero Have provided an alternative idea but have to refactor it further.

Comment: Or even can wrap the option 2 inside an `using` block

Answer (score 0):

Disposable objects must be disposed from the client code, one of the side effects that you will see from what you are doing is that when your consumers use your API they will get code analysis errors (if they use it, many do) like: "CA2213: Disposable fields should be disposed" see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182328.aspx for the details on that error.

Having said the above, you shouldn't be disposing stuff that is absolutely necessary to dispose in the "Execute" method, take these scenarios:

**Scenario#1**

1. You have things like open connections which you must dispose,
   connections are opened in some other method than Execute.
2. An error occurs during the "Do" method execution, the dispose never gets called as execute never got called and the open connection remained open. Note that even if Do never fails on your machine does not gurantee it will not fail on production due to random stuff happening to the machine from another thread.

P.S. the using statements and the entire IDisposable functionality is built to tackle such situations, forcing good devs to dispose no matter what the circumstances are.

**Scenario#2**

1. The execute methods does something disposable worthy e.g. opens a connection and then it does stuff.

In this scenario you don't need the dispose method, you can simply dispose the connection in the execute method by wrapping the connection in a using statement like:

```
public void Execute(object whatever){
    using (var conn = new Connection()){
        //method body
    }
}
```

If you have Scenario#1, you must let the client use the using statement and will have to bear the non-fluency of it (destructors won't cut it), if you have scenario#2 you don't need the dispose at all.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you are trying to dispose of the repository.

If you wish to keep your API intact, I would suggest this:

```
using(var repo = work.Timeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
      .WithRepository(c => c.Users))
{
    IUser user = repo.Do(r => r.LoadByUsername("matt")).Execute();
    //Do whatever with user here if lazy loading.
}
```

I know this sort of breaks your fluent API in two but you can use it in this manner without changing anything at all.

The other option would be to create a wrapper class for the result that maintains a reference to the repository (e.g. ActionFlowExecution) and implements IDisposable:

```
public class ActionFlowExecution<TResult, TRepository> : IDisposable
{
    private TRepository _repository;
    internal ActionFlowExecution(TResult result, TRepository repository)
    {
        Result = result;
        _repository = repository;
    }

    public TResult Result { get; private set; }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if(_repository != null)
        {
            _repository.Dispose();
            _repository = null;
        }
    }
}
```

You could then call your API like this:

```
using(var execution = work
             .Timeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
             .WithRepository(c => c.Users)
             .Do(r => r.LoadByUsername("matt"))
             .Execute())
{
    IUser user = execution.Result;
    //Do whatever with user here 
}
```

I concur with others that it's a bad idea to have the object dispose from the inside. 
I wrote this in five minutes so there might be some typos but I think you will get the general idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can safely do what you mentioned as long as you won't use that object later. The only but very important thing here is the naming. I would call the method `ExecuteAndDispose`. Other options are either breaking your fluent API or are just overkill and also not easiest to use.